# Function to get name of tags returning NULL names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two simple tables to store tags for items:

tags: `id | tag`

`tag` is the name, so each row is unique.

showcase_tags: `id | tag_id | showcase_id`.

I get tags based on the ID of an item, as so:

`$tags = $showcase->getTags($id)`

The functions inside the showcase class:

```
 public function getTags ($id) {

    $stmt = $this->db->getPdo()->prepare(
    "SELECT tag_id FROM showcase_tags WHERE showcase_id = :id
    ");
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tagIds = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $this->getTagNames($tagIds);

  }

 private function getTagNames ($tagIds) {

    $tagNames = [];

    foreach ($tagIds as $id){
      $stmt = $this->db->getPdo()->prepare(
      "SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE id = :id
      ");
      $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $name = $stmt->fetch()['tag'];
      array_push($tagNames, $name);
    }

    return $tagNames;

  }
```

However the array `$tagNames` which is `$tags = $showcase->getTags($id)` just contains `NULL`s rather than the name of the tag, but with the correct number of tags the item has.

Comment: Is there any chance `$tagIds` been populated with array of assoc arrays

Comment: @Chris yeah it's called `tag` not `name`. @Royal I'll check that

Comment: PROTIP: You can use a `JOIN` and do all of this in one query.  `SELECT tag FROM tags JOIN showcase_tags ON tag_id = tags.id WHERE showcase_id = :id`

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's much better, I was able to get it working doing the single query. Thanks!